# Getting a 404 error when deploying Ruby on Rails app to Vercel from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my Rails application on Vercel directly from the respective GitHub repository but, as you can see from the picture, it throws a 404 error. [Vercel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHJak.jpg)

This is my first time using Vercel, so please feel free to point out any mistakes/inaccuracies in my question or methodology.

---

EDIT
To answer @spikerman, this is my config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'items#index'
  get "pages", to: "pages#home"
  get "trigger_service", to: "pages#trigger_service"
  resources :items, only: [:update]
  post "/items/update-all", to: "items#update_all"

end
```

@Greg, oh TwT this website was previously deployed on the free version of Heroku, so I just want to find another easy way to redeploy it. Do you know any other alternatives?

Comment: What path do you try to access, and what does your `config/routes.rb` look like?

Comment: AFAIU vercel is not supposed to host Ruby on Rails apps (https://vercel.com/guides/does-vercel-support-ruby-on-rails-applications). It looks like you need to deploy RoR somewhere else, use it as an API and point your front-end app (deployed on vercel?) to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I edited the post with answers to your comments.